# Взаимодействие между двумя python скриптами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Существует ли какие-нибудь иные методы, кроме как запись в специальный файл одним скриптом и чтение из этого файла другим?

Comment: Веб-сокеты, просто http-запросы, база данных. Ещё вроде как можно связать стандартный вывод одного процесса, со стандартным входом другого, но не уверен, что это можно инициировать изнутри этих скриптов, нужен будет какой-то третий скрипт, который и запустит эти два.

Comment: Смотря что за задача. Возможно вам нужно просто импортировать один скрипт из другого и в импортированном скрипте вызвать какую-то функцию, например.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Взаимодействие, в основном, такое же как и для других языков программирования. На выбор:

1. Работа с общей базой данных. (В том числе, с базой данных на удаленном сервере - для сетевой работы.)
2. Работа с буфером обмена (актуально для GUI приложений)
3. Сокеты https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ipc.html
4. RPC (remote procedure call). Есть несколько библиотек для реализации этой идиомы. В том числе, совместимые с другими языками программирования. Например xmlrpc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html
5. Потоки ввода-вывода (для общения с дочерними процессами).
6. Очереди сообщений https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues
7. Мутексы и прочие примитивы синхронизации https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives
8. shared memory, ограниченная правда, только массивами примитивных типов https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html
9. Выполнение процедур в контексте другого процесса: средствами 'process pool' (тот же  RPC, нов специально созданном пуле процессов) https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool